# Reg avoid 2 phase commit

Tags: spring, jta, spring-transactions, distributed-transactions, atomikos

We have our application in spring and few services are interacting with DB and jms queue.
We have used atomikos to handle 2 phase commit.

The question I have is , from a design perspective, if I do all queue operations at the end of the service execution , so that the probability of error after putting message to queue is very very less, should I still use two phase commit ?

I have used 2 pc in my earlier projects and always feel that if the service logic is coordinated properly like above, chances of corrupt data is very less.

Of course there can be failure cases ( queue will be processed if txn cannot be committed due to network or db failure ) - but they are major issue which has to be dealt with anyways.

Please share your thoughts - by organizing the service logic , can't we avoid JTA in simple scenario like above where only one DB and one jms queue is involved ?

Thanks
Lives.